# 2 UART connected on the same port

Tags: uart

I am curently working on a project where a MCU got only one UART port available, however I need to run two peripherals with UART interface **(not simultaneously)** so I was wondering if I can connect two peripherals UARTs on the same UART of the MCU while playing with enabling and disabling the peripherals one by one for communicating with the MCU?

Your feedbacks and recommendation are appreciated about this situation

Regards

Comment: As long as both peripherals tri-state when disabled, it should be fine.

Comment: Just put a switch on the tx and rx lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to be connected to only one device at a time, you could use a multiplexer to switch between the two chips, like the [NX3L2467](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NX3L2467.pdf):

[image]

You only need a DPDT switch; this is a 4PDT one so you're only using half of the circuit.  But all of the DPDT switches I found had very unfriendly packages to work with such as VQFN, BGA etc.  This part comes in a 16-pin TSSOP package; not as nice as a DIP to work with but doable.  You can get [TSSOP16 to DIP adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JKAIYU4). It also has a very low on-resistance (0.5Ω).  It will work off of 3.3V which I assume is your supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. What configuration you are looking for is something like a [multidrop](http://thegaragelab.com/uart-based-networking-for-microcontrollers/),where the master(uC) is connected to all slaves and all slaves can talk back to the master. However you need flow control among the slaves sending to the master,as all the slaves Tx will be connected to a single Rx of the master.

If you have only a few peripherals(slaves) that need to talk to the master and may be a SPI/I2C available in your master,you could use something like a [Quad Serial UART](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX14830.html). This will simplify software complications

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Can you ellaborate a bit more on flow control issue ? Our project is to use a MCU , one GPS module and one GSM module. We don't need GSM and GSP to run in the same time.

Comment: By flow control i mean that, as long as u ensure the slaves dont send to the master simultaneously or when another slaves is sending to the master,you should be fine

Comment: Yes, it is clear, this is what I was thinking. :) We just organize the dicussion between the different elements so that two guys talk together without being interrupted by a third one...

Comment: That should work then